# general price for different forums php

Tags: php, forums

I have 3 tables = "forums" | "topics" | "users"
In the table "forums" I have a field called "price"
In the table "topics" I have a field called "poster_id"
In the table "users" I have a field called "group_id"
In the three tables have the field user_id

Every forum has a different price, for example forum_id 1, price 0.50
I want to query all of the topics only if the poster_id from topics compatible with group_id in users
For example, only if the user wrote the message is a Registered

After the query, I want to present to all Registered the number of topics that he wrote each forum
And perform general price of all subjects according to the price of every forum.

Example:

Registered, written 3 topics in 3 different forums

```
forum_id 1 = 0.50 $
forum_id 2 = 0.60 $
forum_id 3 = 0.10 $
```

Result:

```
username | earn $ 1.20
```

sorry about my english, im not from usa ;)

thank you!

Comment: (English as mothertongue is not a USA prerogative ;) )

Comment: We need more information about the structure of your tables, as well as what database you're using. Finally, show us the code you've tried to run.

Comment: @Damien But we have such a glorious version of it, second only to Australia's... (Actually, I have a tremendous respect for both British and American English, but I enjoy making fun)

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - Certainly. Everybody knows that USA is one of the main Spanish speaking countries.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT `users`.`username`, SUM(`forums`.`price`)
FROM `topics` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `topics`.`user_id`=`users`.`user_id` AND `users`.`group_id`=100
LEFT JOIN `forums` ON `topics`.`user_id`=`forums`.`user_id`
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1
```